# computing a connection coefficient over a framed open set

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

It is well known that given a connection on a $\mathbb{K}$ vector bundle $E$ over some manifold $M$ with rank $r$, there is a $U\subset M$ is a framed open set with frame $e= \{ e_i \}_{i=1}^r $, such that we have a connection form matrix $\omega \in \Omega ^1 (U, \text{Mat}_{r\times r}(\mathbb{K})$ with respect to this frame. It satisfies
$$
\nabla_X(\tilde{e}_i)=\sum_j \omega^i_j(X)e_j
$$
if $\tilde{e}_i$ is a globally defined section that agrees with $e_i$ on $U$. I understand that given a vector bundle, we can always find framed open sets in which we can define the connection locally.

> Now, my question is given a connection and a framed open set, can we always have a connection form with respect to this frame (we of course still have connection via restriction of $\nabla$)?

I think that this does not hold when the section cannot be extended. Usually, when given a connection, we can compute the connection form by evaluating the expression $\nabla_X(\tilde{e}_i)$ since most cases I have seen, $e_i$ can be extended globally for the given frame so this question never occured to me. But considering my question, does one have to be careful with a choosing a frame in which we wish to find a connection over?

Comment: We should have $\omega\in \Omega^1(U;M_{r,r})$, not $\Omega^1(M;M_{r,r})$

Comment: @Didier yes, I made an edit.

Comment: You also need to edit your $e=\{e_i\}_{i=1}^m$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In full rigour, if $e_j$ is only defined on an open subset $U\subset M$, you cannot consider $\nabla_Xe_j$: the domain of $\nabla$ is $\Gamma(TM)\times \Gamma(TM)$.
As you noted, $e_j$ might not be extendable outside of $U$.

Recall that affine connections are purely local, in the sense that if $X, Y$ and $Z$ are vector fields, if $p\in M$ is a point, and if $Y = Z$ in a neighbourhood of $p$, then $\nabla_XY(p) = \nabla_XZ(p)$.
That in mind, consider the following.

Fix $V$ a precompact open neighbourhood of $p$ in $U$, and let $\varphi$ be a bump function that has compact support in $V$, with $\varphi=1$ around $p$.
Then $\varphi e_j$ is now a global vector field on $M$, and $\nabla_X(\varphi e_j)(p)$ does not depend on $\varphi$.
It is equal to $\nabla_XY(p)$ for any $Y$ that is equal to $e_j$ in a small neighbourhood of $p$.

This way, you are able to assign a unique value $\nabla_Xe_j(p)$ for any $p\in U$, even though the vector field $e_j$ isn't extendible to $M$.
The corresponding function $p\mapsto \nabla_Xe_j (p)$ is a vector field on $U$, and we can consider its coefficients in the frame $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$.
This way, we have defined a unique connection form $\omega$ for the framed open subset $U$, whether or not the elements of the frame can be extended to $M$.

Comment: Does this approach work in practice? or is this purely a theoretical framework? For example, if I am given a formula for the global connection, can we perform the above procedure for each point by multiplying the local section by a smooth bump function turning it into a global section and thereby using the global formula to compute the (local) coefficient at each point?  Or does introducing the bump function lead us into a rabbit hole that is difficult to deal with in practice?

Comment: @Alg-top The connection is a tensor (on $U$, not not $M$!) so it is a pointwise function: no need to extend anything to use it. If you already know the frame and the connection form, you know the whole connection. Conversely, if you know the frame and the connection, my answer shows that you know the connection form by doing local computations without using any extension